# Installing Vapor Toolbox on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: toolbox, vapor, ubuntu-17.04

$ curl -sL toolbox.vapor.sh | bash 
 
This script is deprecated.
Please install through Homebrew or APT

$ eval "$(curl -sL https://apt.vapor.sh)" 
Only Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 16.10 are supported. 
You are running 17.04

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 
or i have to wait Vapor support.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the scripts at https://apt.vapor.sh/ manually to install everything you need. Be warned though that Swift itself doesn't support Ubuntu 17 so there is a high possibility it may not work.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You don't happen to know where the equivalent Mac script is, do you?

Comment: https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/install-on-macos/#add-homebrew-tap - use brew to install it from the Vapor tap